# Php Curl Select Options in Dynamic Dropdown Form fields

Tags: php, post, curl, libcurl

I searched and searched how to create a php script to select (2) specific dynamic drop down fields when accessing a url, but when I run my code below, it shows the url, but the two drop downs are not selected.

The options and their corresponding values look like this:
[image: img1]

[image: img2]

The corresponding code I'm using:

```
$ch = curl_init();
 $data_fields = array('year' => '2014',
               'makes' => '200002038'
              ); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://thesitesurl.com/location-to-file-that-form-exists-on-here');  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_fields);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

 curl_close ($ch);
```

The output when I run the code currently is - it displays the contents of the `CURLOPT_URL` on the page, but none of the form options are selected.

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: make sure your posting all the vars in the form

Comment: So, if the selects have multiple <option> they need to be posted too?

Comment: no no, check the form if it has any other `<input` also you need to post the form to `<form action=url`

Comment: The action of the form is action="results.html". Where do I need to set the action url? The current CURLOPT_URL is the url where the form resides, but where the form resides is not where it is submitting to. An answer entry here may be helpful to not clog up the comments

Comment: Another thing I noticed is the method is method="get" for this form..

Comment: The form itself though is a bunch of <select> and not <input>